# compiling win32 official example with VS 2019 build tools (cl command) encounters _wWinMain@16 error, how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to render a window by using the exact code in the [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program)

I'm not sure whether the error "_wWinMain@16" refers to the 16th line of code.

```
doing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetMessageW@16 refe
renced in function _wWinMain@16
doing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__TranslateMessage@4
referenced in function _wWinMain@16
doing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DispatchMessageW@4
referenced in function _wWinMain@16
```

which is

```
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
```

here is the declaration of WindowProc

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

I'm using vs2019 build tools on windows 7 sp1.

What am I missing?

Comment: The 16 has nothing to do with the line of code, this error means that for whatever reason WinMain itself was not found by the linker. By the time the linker is running the code has already been compiled and input lines are all but meaningless. Show the how WinMain was declared instead.

Comment: The [GetMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) documentation mentions that it requires linking to `user32.lib`, and the same goes for the others. The quoted errors suggest that the `.lib` is not linked, resulting in the unresolved externals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user32.lib` is required to link as @dxiv pointed out.

You can try the following command line:

```
cl test.cpp /link /subsystem:windows user32.lib
```